# How do I intergrate Google Cloud Filestore with my existing Compute Engine instance running Worpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, high-availability, google-cloud-filestore

I have an instance running Linux Debian 9 and Apache2 web server.
 I used the Bitnami setup and created a WordPress multisite. So what I have done so far is, I have used a Google Cloud storage bucket for all my media files as to not fill up my instance drive.
 I have also separated my SQL database from the instance using Cloud SQL.
So the files that are on the instance are the Wordpress installation files as well as the SSL files. I am using Let's Encrypt to generate my SSL certificates. I have a wildcard cert for my domain. And each site is then mapped to its own domain name using my static IP and Virtual Host configuration on Apache to direct the domain to the correct site.

Question: Is it a good idea to separate my static files system using Google Cloud Filestore? ie: the WordPress installation files, plugins etc. And how would I go about doing this? Do I just mount the entire directory on Filestore? Also when I mount a directory to filestore are the files then removed from the instance and served from Filestore? (Am I understanding correctly?)

Comment: Looks like the WordPress installation files do not require a lot of space, and they would not be used and shared by other applications . The objective of Cloud Filestore is to manage the file storage service for applications that require a [filesystem interface and a shared filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/). Could you share the reason why would you like to seperate the static files of the WordPress installation?

Comment: He wants it for high availability and scaling, since WP is a stateful app, it needs a shared NAS in between webserver instances. What he can do is to spin up apache servers in GCE, and mount the /www (contains WP files) from the file store. He can also use Cloud SQL as db for further high availability. This will allow him to use GCE only for apache instances. Or alternatively he can use kubernetes. OR app engine. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/new-cloud-filestore-service-brings-gcp-users-high-performance-file-storage